# Button stops working after swiping up app in control center SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, swiftui

My app is literally the default Xcode project with just a button that prints "Working" to the console when pressed. The button works when I first open the app on my phone. The button still works if I exit and then reopen the app, or even turn off my phone and then reopen the app.

But when I swipe up to go to the Control Center and then swipe up on my app and then reopen it, the button no longer works.

Occasionally (but not every time I have tested), Xcode will say: "Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9". What am I doing wrong? Again, the code is just the SwiftUI Project starter code and this:

```
Button("Click me", action: {
    print("Works")
})
```

Comment: The app is still working, it's just the debugger session that is being terminated.  Which is why you can't see any output on the console.  When this happens, in Xcode go into the Debug menu, choose attach to process, and select your app, you willl then see the output appear again.

Comment: @flanker this would make sense, especially given the termination error statement. However, this also does not work. I launch the app, swipe up and reopen it, attach to debug, and the buttons till does not print to Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Killing the app while it's running from Xcode is not a very nice thing to do to Xcode, which becomes confused and is no longer "hooked up" to the running app. You need to unconfuse Xcode:

- You're not waiting long enough before you "reopen it": after the swipe up, count to ten, slowly, and then relaunch the app from Xcode.
- Another good idea is to check that the app has also stopped in Xcode itself: after the swipe up, switch to Xcode and hit its Stop button, count to three, slowly, then relaunch the app from Xcode.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of the bullet points work. I still do not see any print statements in the Xcode window after reopening the app as suggested and pressing the button.

Comment: Because you didn't relaunch the app _from Xcode_ as my bullet points tell you to do. If you just relaunch the app by tapping its icon in the Simulator or whatever, Xcode knows nothing about that and there is no link to the "Xcode window" at all. In that case you have to explicit _attach_ to the running app, as flanker has already told you.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean relaunching by pressing the triangle "start active scheme" run button. This does allow the button to function normally, but I don't think that this is what I am testing

Comment: Well, it's up to you. As flanker has already told you, if you do it your way, the button is working perfectly. It's just that the `print` statement does nothing visible because there is no linkage to Xcode. I suggest that you make the button do something responsive _in the app interface_ so that you can see that the tap is working even without Xcode's involvement. — In any case, I stand by my answer. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Your answer makes sense with the information that the debug console is terminated when I refresh the app. Makes sense now, thank you. I will be nicer to Xcode in the future